React Native - How to disable default android Splash Screen
I create a React Native app and for this app, I create my custom Splash Screen using npm i react-native-splash-screen.
But on app run, It 1st show the default android splash screen and then it show the splash screen, I create.
So, I want to disable the default android splash screen.

Add this command in your style.xml file before closing the style tag.
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

Path to style.xml file:
[YourProjectName]\android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
